# Get population by latitude, longitude and radius

Tags: javascript, php, api, geolocation

> > We are creating a system in which we need to show how much(approx)
> >     population(people) are there with in some radius.

For location we have latitude and longitude.This system is built in PHP. I try to find this in google but not found any solution. I also checked some stackoverflow answers but not got want is needed.

Any solution which can give this result would be accepted, As we really want this in our project.

I have not much idea about the `tags` for this question so please edit if you can.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using some API or what? Where are You taking data from?

Comment: I am asking for API which can provide me this data.